# Optimizing docker image size

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I am building a docker image for my python app using the base image `python:3.5-slim-buster`.

I am running the below command inside the `Dockerfile`:

`RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` which has `torch` library in the requirements file.

After building the image it is having a size of `2.29 GB`. But if I build the image without torch inside the requirements file, it has only ~900 MB.

when I manually run the image and check inside the container:

The torch (`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch`) directory is `1.3GB`.

So even if I do a multistage build and try to copy the contents from 
`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` to a new image, I suppose it is not going to help me.

Is there any other standard optimization practice which can help me to reduce the image size?

Comment: the cpu-only version of pytorch is much smaller than the CUDA version if you're not already using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a trained model of some kind from `pytorch` (usually neural network) you should indeed use multistage Docker build as follows (IMO at least):

### 1. Training model and exporting

Write your script as per usual, including all dependencies you need. Train your model and save it as artifact using torchscript's [`torch.jit.script`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html).

### 2. Second stage

Using C++ write inference code loading your net and compile the source (use [`libtorch`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html)).

### 3. Final image

Copy binary from previous step and put it is as Docker's entrypoint so you can run it as disposable neural net within container.